# C# MVC How to change an uploaded pdf file name prior to further processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the uploaded pdf's file name prior to saving on Server and saving the name/reference in my database.

In my controller I have this:

```
var pdf = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myPDF"];
```

I want to change the file name, then I'll save the file and do the database work. How do I change the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It technically doesn't *have* a file name until it's written to the file system.  Anything it has in-memory is just meta-data associated with the byte stream.  In the context of an `HttpPostedFile` [those meta-data properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpPostedFile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) appear to be read-only.

Presumably at some point in your code you're [saving the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That's where you'd specify the file name:

```
var pdf = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myPDF"];
pdf.SaveAs("anyCustomFileName.pdf");
```

Comment: "Anything it has in-memory is just meta-data associated with the byte stream" Specifically, the filename present in the request is the name of the file from the client's file system. As David says, it doesn't exist on your server yet at this point.